# Create NEWS.md from github commits with RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

is there a proper way to create NOT by hand a NEWS file for a package in R/RStudio?

Is it ok if i find a way to use the description of commits from the github repo to create this file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to interact with the GitHub API using R([REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/)) to read the commits

You can use [R Bindings for the Github v3 API](https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub)
I'm not sure if it cover all API needed to read the commits (or you can deploy it)

You should take into account that you should standard all changes/bug fixes and version number to get meaningful commits in the NEWS file.

My advice Do it manually (by hand) :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW - anyone who is looking here, look at the `fledge` package: https://github.com/krlmlr/fledge.  It seems to do what you want.